# R: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names

Tags: r

I am using a script that has worked in similar contexts in the past, but now it is turning up an error.

Below is my script.

```
  pulse1<-NULL
 timePeriods<-c("Bin 1", "Bin 2", "Bin 3")
 weeks<-c("Jan25-Feb8", "Feb15- March15", "Mar22-April5")


 for (columnNumber in 1:3)
 {
   temp.data<-data.frame(Student=pulse$Student, Question=pulse$Question, Type=pulse$Type, 
                         timePeriods= timePeriods[columnNumber], week=weeks[columnNumber], 
                         Rating=pulse[, columnNumber+3])
   pulse1<-rbind(pulse1, temp.data)  
 }
 head(pulse1)
```

This code is meant to create a new table that looks like this:

```
> head(pulse1)
  Student Question Type timePeriods       week    Rating
1  965873        Q  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.0000000
2  841903        Q  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 2.0000000
3  959200       Q2  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.0000000
4  959200       Q8  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 1.0000000
5  789331       Q2  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 1.0000000
6  789331      Q12  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.6666667
```

However, instead of combining the three columns after "week" into 1 "Rating" column, it is just omitting the columns "Bin2" and "Bin3".

```
> head(pulse1)
  Student Question Type timePeriods       week      Bin1
1  965873        Q  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.0000000
2  841903        Q  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 2.0000000
3  959200       Q2  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.0000000
4  959200       Q8  FYS       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 1.0000000
5  789331       Q2  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 1.0000000
6  789331      Q12  SNR       Bin 1 Jan25-Feb8 0.6666667
```

Furthermore, when I run through my script (above), it turns up this error:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Other than running through the above code, all I do is import and organize the data (pulse) that I have attached below.

Thank you!

Please find my data below.

```
> dput(pulse)
structure(list(Question = c("Q", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q2", "Q12", 
"Q12", "Q2", "Q10", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q", "Q12", 
"Q10", "Q", "Q12", "Q8", "Q10", "Q8", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q2", 
"Q", "Q12", "Q", "Q8", "Q10", "Q2", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q", "Q2", 
"Q8", "Q10", "Q8", "Q12", "Q", "Q10", "Q12", "Q10", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q2", "Q10", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q2", "Q8", 
"Q10", "Q", "Q2", "Q12", "Q", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q12", "Q8", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q10", "Q12", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q2", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", 
"Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q2", "Q8", "Q8", "Q12", "Q10", "Q12", 
"Q2", "Q10", "Q10", "Q8", "Q", "Q8", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", 
"Q12", "Q", "Q2", "Q8", "Q10", "Q12"), Type = c("FYS", "SNR", 
"FYS", "FYS", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", 
"SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "SNR", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", 
"FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS", "FYS"), Student = c(965873L, 841903L, 
959200L, 959200L, 789331L, 789331L, 832929L, 841903L, 841903L, 
852125L, 852125L, 852125L, 852125L, 876406L, 876406L, 879972L, 
879972L, 885650L, 903303L, 903303L, 952797L, 952797L, 957206L, 
957759L, 957759L, 959200L, 965873L, 968728L, 968728L, 789331L, 
789331L, 789331L, 805933L, 826523L, 826523L, 826523L, 832929L, 
832929L, 832929L, 832929L, 841903L, 841903L, 843618L, 843618L, 
843618L, 852125L, 876406L, 876406L, 876406L, 879972L, 879972L, 
885650L, 885650L, 885650L, 888712L, 888712L, 888712L, 903303L, 
903303L, 903303L, 952797L, 952797L, 952797L, 957206L, 957206L, 
957206L, 957759L, 957759L, 959200L, 959200L, 965873L, 965873L, 
967416L, 967416L, 967416L, 967416L, 968728L, 968728L, 968728L, 
971179L, 971179L, 971179L, 805933L, 805933L, 805933L, 805933L, 
826523L, 826523L, 838607L, 838607L, 838607L, 838607L, 838607L, 
843618L, 843618L, 879972L, 885650L, 888712L, 888712L, 957206L, 
957759L, 965873L, 967416L, 971179L, 971179L, 796882L, 796882L, 
796882L, 796882L, 796882L, 827911L, 827911L, 827911L, 827911L, 
827911L, 830271L, 830271L, 830271L, 830271L, 830271L, 831487L, 
831487L, 831487L, 831487L, 831487L, 834598L, 834598L, 834598L, 
834598L, 834598L, 836364L, 836364L, 836364L, 836364L, 836364L, 
839802L, 839802L, 839802L, 839802L, 839802L, 855524L, 855524L, 
855524L, 855524L, 855524L, 873527L, 873527L, 873527L, 873527L, 
873527L, 885409L, 885409L, 885409L, 885409L, 885409L, 894218L, 
894218L, 894218L, 894218L, 894218L, 928026L, 928026L, 928026L, 
928026L, 928026L, 932196L, 932196L, 932196L, 932196L, 932196L, 
955389L, 955389L, 955389L, 955389L, 955389L, 956952L, 956952L, 
956952L, 956952L, 956952L, 962490L, 962490L, 962490L, 962490L, 
962490L, 969005L, 969005L, 969005L, 969005L, 969005L, 975424L, 
975424L, 975424L, 975424L, 975424L, 976863L, 976863L, 976863L, 
976863L, 976863L, 981621L, 981621L, 981621L, 981621L, 981621L
), Bin1 = c(0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
1.66666666666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 1, -0.666666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 1, 1.66666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, -0.666666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
-0.666666666666667, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.333333333333333, 
-0.666666666666667, 0, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0, -1, -1.33333333333333, 
-1, -1.33333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -0.333333333333333, 
-1, 0, -1, -1, -0.666666666666667, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.666666666666667, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Bin2 = c(-1.5, 1.75, 0.75, 1.75, -0.5, 0.25, 
1, 2, 0.75, -0.5, -0.5, -0.25, 1, 1, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 2.5, 
0, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.25, -0.5, -0.5, 0, -1.5, -1.25, -1, 
0, 1, 0.75, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.25, 1, -0.25, 1, 0, -1, -1.25, 
-0.75, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 
-0.25, 0, 1.5, 0, -1.25, 0, -0.75, 0.25, -1, -1.25, -1.25, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.25, 0.5, -1.5, -1.25, -1.25, -0.25, 1.25, 0.25, -1, -2, 
-2, -2, -0.75, 0, 0, -0.75, -0.75, -0.5, -0.5, -1, -1, -1.75, 
-0.75, -1.25, -1.5, -0.5, -1.5, -2.5, 0, 0, -1, 0.25, -2.75, 
-3, -2.75, -0.5, -0.25, -0.25, 0, -0.75, -1.75, 1, -0.25, -0.75, 
-0.25, 1, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -0.75, -1, 0, 
-1, -0.25, -0.25, 0.5, -0.75, 0.25, -0.75, 0.75, -0.75, -0.75, 
-0.25, -0.75, -0.75, 1, -0.75, 0, 0, 1, 0.25, 0, -0.25, -1.5, 
-0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 
0, 0.25, 0, 0.75, 1.25, -0.25, 0.75, 0.25, 0.25, 1.75, 0, 0.75, 
0.75, 1, 0.25, 1, 0, 2, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -2, 0, 0, 1, 
-2, -1.5, -1.25, -0.75), Bin3 = c(-0.333333333333333, 2, 1, 2, 
0, 0.666666666666667, 1, 2, 1, -0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0, 1, 0, 0.333333333333333, 3, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 
1.33333333333333, -1, -0.666666666666667, -1.66666666666667, 
-0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667, 
-1, -0.333333333333333, 1, 1, -2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.666666666666667, 
-0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, -1, 
-1, 0.333333333333333, 0, 1, 1, 0.666666666666667, 0, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1.66666666666667, 0, -0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
-0.666666666666667, 0, -1, -1.66666666666667, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
-2.33333333333333, -1.33333333333333, -1.66666666666667, 0, 2, 
1, -1, -2, -2, -2, -1, 0.333333333333333, -1, -2, -1, -1, -1, 
-1.33333333333333, -1.33333333333333, -2, -2, -1.33333333333333, 
-2, -1, -1, -3.33333333333333, 0, 0, -1, 0.666666666666667, -3.33333333333333, 
-3, -2.66666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, 1, 
0, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667, 0, -0.666666666666667, 
-0.666666666666667, 0, -0.333333333333333, -1.33333333333333, 
0, -1.33333333333333, 0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 
0, -0.666666666666667, -0.666666666666667, -0.333333333333333, 
1, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0.333333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
1, 0, -1, -1.66666666666667, -0.666666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 
1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0, 1, 
0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, -1, 
-0.333333333333333, -0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 
-1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1, -2, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, -2, -2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -205L), .Names = c("Question", 
"Type", "Student", "Bin1", "Bin2", "Bin3"))
```

Comment: If I run your code as it is I get your desired output. That is, with `Rating` as column name

Comment: @simone does that just mean I should close and reopen R? I'm an R beginner and i'm not sure why it is doing this or what to do here.

Comment: here is what I did: I assigned your `structure` above to `pulse` and ran your loop. You can try doing that as a start

Comment: @simone 
So I did that and I am still getting the same error. Any other thoughts? Thank you for your help.

Comment: try updating the question showing exactly what you are doing. that way might be easier to help

Comment: @simone
I updated it as best I could. Really, apart from organizing the data set that I dput above and running the loop I included, I haven't done anything. Perhaps the problem is stemming from an error I had earlier when organizing the data..?

Answer (score 0):

First pulse1 should be an empty data.frame

```
pulse1<-data.frame()
```

You could just add new colnames

```
colnames(pulse1)<-c("Student","Question","Type","timePeriods","week","Rating")
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! On further inspection, the problem is actually affecting my data however, so just changing the labels won't work. Instead of moving the last three columns into one column like I want, it is just taking the first column.